# Problema ao retornar dados em view com laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

Estou tentando trazer dados para uma view e não estou tendo sucesso.

tenho minha classe de Pessoa.

```
class Pessoa extends Model {

public function telefones()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Telefone::class);
}
```

e em minha classe de Telefone tenho.

```
class Telefone extends Model
{
public function pessoa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Pessoa::class);
}

}
```

as migrations estão com os relacionamentos

```
    Schema::create('pessoas', function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        // outros relacionamentos e colunas

        $table->integer('id_telefone')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('id_telefone')->references('id')->on('telefones');            
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

enfim tenho a view de visualização dos dados.

```
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Telefone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    @foreach($pessoasfisicas as $pessoafisica)

    <tbody>


    <tr>

            <td>{{$pessoafisica->nome}}</td>
             @foreach($pessoafisica->telefones() as $tel)
            <td>{{ $tel->telefone }}</td>
            @endforeach
        <td><h4>



    </tr>

    </tbody>

@endforeach
```

quando os dados são retornados não estão retornando o telefone, ha alguma melhoria nesse exemplo para solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Acho q tua migration que esta errada.
O id de pessoa que deveria estar na tabela de Telefone, e não o contrario.

Comment: realmente não sei o que estava fazendo, deu um apagão e acabei escrevendo errado.